# Has the usage of body mass index caused historical harm and been utilized for racial exclusion?

Tags: medical-science, racism

[ama-assn.org](https://www.ama-assn.org/delivering-care/public-health/ama-use-bmi-alone-imperfect-clinical-measure) (American Medical Association) writes regarding [BMI (body mass index)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Body_mass_index)

> The House of Delegates adopted new policy recognizing the issues with using BMI as a measurement because:
>
> - Of the historical harm of BMI.
> - Of the use of BMI for racist exclusion.
> - BMI cutoffs are based primarily on data collected from previous generations of non-Hispanic white populations and does not consider a person’s gender or ethnicity.

- Has the utilization of body mass index caused historical harm? If so, what was the harm?
- Has body mass index measurement been used for racial exclusion?

By [harm](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/harm) I understand "physical or mental damage : INJURY"

Comment: There is nothing in the claim itself to back up your choice of definition for "harm". If they're using a different definition, it's your interpretation that's wrong, not the claim.

Comment: Also, clicking through to the link, it states pretty clearly what they're talking about by "harm", e.g. "the use of BMI is problematic when used to diagnose and treat individuals with eating disorders". Perhaps _those_ are the claims you should be asking about?